# Not understanding seg faults when I'm using pointers with structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I keep getting seg faults and I can't for the life of me figure out why!  I tried posting just the simplest example I could write up in code (what you see) to try and figure out the problem but I am stuck.  Anything will help!!!!

```
int main()
{
    int i1, i2;
    struct intPtrs
    {
        int *p1;
        int *p2;
    };

    struct intPtrs *myIntPtr;

    i1 = 100;
    i2 = 200;

    myIntPtr->p1 = &i1;
    myIntPtr->p1 = &i2;

    printf("\ni1 = %i, i2 = %i\n",myIntPtr->p1,myIntPtr->p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for your struct. You need malloc (don't forget to free).

So, your code should look like this (there are others problems, check my code):

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc()

// declare the struct outside main()
struct intPtrs {
  int *p1;
  int *p2;
};

// typedef the struct, just for less typing
// afterwards. Notice that I use the extension
// _t, in order to let the reader know that
// this is a typedef
typedef struct intPtrs intPtrs_t;

int main() {
  int i1, i2;

  // declare a pointer for my struct
  // and allocate memory for it
  intPtrs_t *myIntPtr = malloc(sizeof(intPtrs_t));

  // check if allocation is OK
  if (!myIntPtr) {
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    return -1;
  }

  i1 = 100;
  i2 = 200;

  myIntPtr->p1 = &i1;
  myIntPtr->p2 = &i2; // here you had p1

  // you want to print the numbers, thus you need what the p1 and p2
  // pointers point to, thus the asterisk before the opening parenthesis
  printf("\ni1 = %d, i2 = %d\n", *(myIntPtr->p1), *(myIntPtr->p2));

  // DON'T FORGET TO FREE THE DYNAMICALLY
  // ALLOCATED MEMORY
  free(myIntPtr);

  return 0;
}
```

When I use structs, I also use a typedef, as you can see in my example [here](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/structs-c/).

Comment: +1 Alternatively declare struct variable instead of pointer and use `.` (dot) operator instead. If program is about to exit, then `free` is not really needed, but anyway it's good pratice to remember about it.

Comment: That fixes it, thank you very much.  So if I wasn't using a pointer with the struct, I shouldn't have to use malloc, right?

Comment: Correct. You wouldn't need to dynamically allocate memory. Nice question though, here is my +1. :) @like9orphanz